# Ajax alert inside function not works

Tags: ajax

First alert : `alert('<?php echo t_lang('M_FRM_PLEASE_WAIT_WHILE_FILE_OR_IMAGE_IS_BEING_UPLOADED_._IF_FILE_SIZE_IS_BIG_IT_CAN_TAKE_SOME_TIME_._PLEASE_DO_NOT_CLOSE_TAB');?>');` does not work unless I put second alert out of function call: `alert();`

```
$('input[name="btn_submit"]').click(function second(){
            var step = <?php echo $_REQUEST['step']?>;
            var dealid= <?php echo $_GET['edit']?>;
            var ur="imagecheck.php?dealid="+dealid;
                if (step == 1) {
                    
                $.ajax({
                url: ur,
                type: "GET",
                header: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
                    success: function(y) {
                    
                        if(y=='true'){
                            alert('<?php echo t_lang('M_FRM_PLEASE_WAIT_WHILE_FILE_OR_IMAGE_IS_BEING_UPLOADED_._IF_FILE_SIZE_IS_BIG_IT_CAN_TAKE_SOME_TIME_._PLEASE_DO_NOT_CLOSE_TAB');?>'); 
                            } else {
                                alert(dealid);
                            }
                        }
                });

                alert(); // if I don't add this first alert is not showed up. 
                }
            });
```

I tried almost everything but still can not understand why first alert relies on second alert. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I am adding the codes below which is all about ajax in my file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        

        $('input[name="btn_submit"]').click(function first(){
            
               var com_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['logged_user']['company_id']?>;
               var co_type=$('#co_type').val(); 
               var ur="check_no_of_deals.php?company_id="+com_id;
                if(co_type==0){
          $.ajax({
            url: ur,
            type: "GET",
            header: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
                success: function(t) {
                  
                    if(t == 'true'){

                        } else {
                           alert('<?php echo t_lang('M_FRM_YOU_HAVE_ALREADY_ADDED_DEAL_TODAY');?>'); 
                            window.location.href='http://deals.az/merchant/company-deals.php';
                           
                        }
                     }
            });
      }

            });

//bizim kod basladi
$('input[name="btn_submit"]').click(function second(){
            var step = <?php echo $_REQUEST['step']?>;
            var dealid= <?php echo $_GET['edit']?>;
            var ur="imagecheck.php?dealid="+dealid;
                if (step == 1) {
                    
                $.ajax({
                url: ur,
                type: "GET",
                header: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
                    success: function(t)(y) => {
                        if(t=='true'){
                            alert('<?php echo t_lang('M_FRM_PLEASE_WAIT_WHILE_FILE_OR_IMAGE_IS_BEING_UPLOADED_._IF_FILE_SIZE_IS_BIG_IT_CAN_TAKE_SOME_TIME_._PLEASE_DO_NOT_CLOSE_TAB');?>'); 
                            } else {
                              alert(dealid);
                            }
                        }
                });

              // alert();
                }
            });
//bizim kod bitti

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try replacing to arrow function

```
$.ajax({
   ...
    success: (y) => {
        if(y=='true'){
        ...
        }
    }
   ...
})
```

the difference between an arrow function and a regular function is by their `this`
so when you pass the regular function it becomes part of the ajax call or the Jquery object.
but the arrow function stays where you see it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but did not work. I think the reason is different here. I added all ajax codes in my first post.

Comment: I tried in chrome instead of mozilla and it worked. what can be cause of this?

Comment: actually. nothing I can think about.
I would check that the ajax is actually called in the network DevTool.
and try to do the alert without any PHP in it. maybe it will change something.